# BufferUnderflowException exception while doing getLong when buffer is allocated 14 bytes

Tags: java

Very small piece of code but i am completely surprised with the behavior. I have a 14 byte key which is in a byte array.I put this byte array into a ByteBuffer then doing a getLong gives me a BufferUnderflowException. Can't understand why?

```
    byte key[] = new byte[14];

    key[13] = (byte) 3;
    key[12] = (byte) 21;
    key[11] = (byte) 1;
    key[10] = (byte) 15;
    key[9]  = (byte) 66;
    key[8]  = (byte) 64;

    key[7]  = (byte) 3;
    key[6]  = (byte) 65;
    key[5]  = (byte) -10;
    key[4]  = (byte) -65;
    key[3]  = (byte) 3;
    key[2]  = (byte) 65;
    key[1]  = (byte) -10;
    key[0]  = (byte) -65;


    ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(14);
    b.put(key);
    long l = b.getLong();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation of "put" the method for other bytebuffers is clarified that the position of the buffer is incremented by the number of put bytes. This seems to be the same for byte arrays. Therefore after your put operation the position in the buffer is at 14 and 0 bytes are left to get a long value which needs 8 bytes.

java doc of "put": "[...]The positions of both buffers are then incremented by n. [...]"

Answer (score 3):

```
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(14);
b.put(key, 0, key.length);
long l = b.getLong(0);
```

you should must specify the index while getting the long